# How to select join column in hql

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am using hibernate and have three tables: Version, Location and Arc.

The Version bean is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "version")
public class Version {
  private String id;
  private List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
  private List<Arc> arcs = new ArrayList<Arc>();

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "versionid", nullable = false)
  public List<Location> getLocations() {
    return locations;
  }
  public void setLocations(List<Location> locations) {
    this.locations = locations;
  }

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "versionid", nullable = false)
  public List<Arc> getArcs() {
    return arcs;
  }
  public void setArcs(List<Arc> arcs) {
    this.arcs = arcs;
  }

  //other setters and getters
       ...
}
```

The Location bean is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "location")
public class Location {
  private int id;
  private String locationId;

  //other getters and setters
  ...

}
```

The Arc bean is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "arc")
public class Arc {
  private int id;

  //other setters and getters
   ...
}
```

Now I am trying to access the data using hql. I can do the query like:

```
select v.id,l.locationId from Version v, Location l where versionid=v.id;
```

But I get error `could not resolve property: versionid` when I do this:

```
 select v.id,l.locationId from Version v, Location l where l.versionid=v.id;
```

I also get this error  `ambiguous versionid` when I do this:

```
select a.id, l.locationId from Arc a, Location l where versionid = '1';
```

My question is how to get the join column versionid in Location or Arc table using hql and how to distinguish the two join column with the same name versionid? 
Any ideas?
Thanks a lot.

Someone has suggested me that I should add versionId in Location tables. However, if I do that, I will get error of duplicate columns as the join column has automatically create a versionid column.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `v.id = versionid`? Also where is your versionid in the code? There is `locationId` declared in "version" table. but no `versionid`.

Comment: The locationId is in the location table and the versionid is a join column declared in Version.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your `versionid` in the code? I mean the declaration. There is `locationId` declared in "version" table. but no `versionid`. Check your query where you are saying

```
`select v.id, l.locationId from Version v`
```

In fact your error says "Could not resolve the property *versionid* ". Because you have no property versionid declared in the first place.

Comment: Actually I can not add versionId in location table as it will cause duplicate column